# How to build ros for python3 (melodic) on jetson Xavier Nx?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ros, nvidia-jetson

I am trying to run instance segmentation using ROS melodic but I want to build ROS for python3 instead of python2. I am using a jetson Xaver NX with Jetpack 4.4 and Ubuntu 18. I am following the steps as shown in [ROS to python3](https://www.miguelalonsojr.com/blog/robotics/ros/python3/2019/08/20/ros-melodic-python-3-build.html). All steps worked fine, however when I reached the last step to catkin build, I got the following error

```
akshay@jetson:~/ros_catkin_ws$ catkin build
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Profile:                     default
Extending:             [env] /home/akshay/catkin_ws/devel:/opt/ros/melodic
Workspace:                   /home/akshay/ros_catkin_ws
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Build Space:        [exists] /home/akshay/ros_catkin_ws/build
Devel Space:        [exists] /home/akshay/ros_catkin_ws/devel
Install Space:     [missing] /home/akshay/ros_catkin_ws/install
Log Space:          [exists] /home/akshay/ros_catkin_ws/logs
Source Space:       [exists] /home/akshay/ros_catkin_ws/src
DESTDIR:            [unused] None
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Devel Space Layout:          linked
Install Space Layout:        merged
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Additional CMake Args:       -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
Additional Make Args:        None
Additional catkin Make Args: None
Internal Make Job Server:    True
Cache Job Environments:      False
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Whitelisted Packages:        None
Blacklisted Packages:        rqt_rviz rviz_plugin_tutorials librviz_tutorial
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Workspace configuration appears valid.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[build] Found '237' packages in 0.0 seconds.                                   
Warning: generated devel space setup files have been deleted.
Starting  >>> catkin                                                           
_______________________________________________________________________________
Errors     << catkin:cmake /home/akshay/ros_catkin_ws/logs/catkin/build.cmake.003.log
CMake Error at /home/akshay/ros_catkin_ws/src/catkin/cmake/empy.cmake:30 (message):
  Unable to find either executable 'empy' or Python module 'em'...  try
  installing the package 'python-empy'
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/all.cmake:164 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:8 (include)


cd /home/akshay/ros_catkin_ws/build/catkin; catkin build --get-env catkin | catkin env -si  /usr/bin/cmake /home/akshay/ros_catkin_ws/src/catkin --no-warn-unused-cli -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/akshay/ros_catkin_ws/devel/.private/catkin -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/akshay/ros_catkin_ws/install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release; cd -

...............................................................................
Failed     << catkin:cmake                                    [ Exited with code 1 ]
Failed    <<< catkin                                          [ 0.6 seconds ]  
Abandoned <<< genmsg                                          [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< gencpp                                          [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< geneus                                          [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< genlisp                                         [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< gennodejs                                       [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< genpy                                           [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< bond_core                                       [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< cmake_modules                                   [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< class_loader                                    [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< common_msgs                                     [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< common_tutorials                                [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< cpp_common                                      [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< desktop                                         [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< desktop_full                                    [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< diagnostics                                     [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< executive_smach                                 [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< gazebo_dev                                      [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< gazebo_ros_pkgs                                 [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< geometry                                        [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< geometry_tutorials                              [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< gl_dependency                                   [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< image_common                                    [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< image_pipeline                                  [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< image_transport_plugins                         [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< laser_pipeline                                  [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< media_export                                    [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< message_generation                              [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< message_runtime                                 [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< mk                                              [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< nodelet_core                                    [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< orocos_kdl                                      [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< perception                                      [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< perception_pcl                                  [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< python_orocos_kdl                               [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< qt_dotgraph                                     [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< qt_gui                                          [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< qt_gui_py_common                                [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< qwt_dependency                                  [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< robot                                           [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< ros                                             [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< ros_base                                        [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< ros_comm                                        [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< ros_core                                        [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< ros_environment                                 [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< ros_tutorials                                   [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< rosbag_migration_rule                           [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< rosbash                                         [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< rosboost_cfg                                    [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< rosbuild                                        [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< rosclean                                        [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< roscpp_core                                     [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< roscpp_traits                                   [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< roscreate                                       [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< rosgraph                                        [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< roslang                                         [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< roslint                                         [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< roslisp                                         [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< rosmake                                         [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< rosmaster                                       [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< rospack                                         [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< roslib                                          [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< rosparam                                        [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< rospy                                           [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< rosservice                                      [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< rostime                                         [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< roscpp_serialization                            [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< python_qt_binding                               [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< roslaunch                                       [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< rosunit                                         [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< angles                                          [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< rosconsole                                      [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< pluginlib                                       [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< qt_gui_cpp                                      [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< resource_retriever                              [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< rosconsole_bridge                               [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< roslz4                                          [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< rostest                                         [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< rqt_action                                      [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< rqt_bag                                         [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< rqt_bag_plugins                                 [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< rqt_common_plugins                              [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< rqt_console                                     [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< rqt_dep                                         [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< rqt_graph                                       [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< rqt_gui                                         [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< rqt_logger_level                                [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< rqt_moveit                                      [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< rqt_msg                                         [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< rqt_nav_view                                    [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< rqt_plot                                        [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< rqt_pose_view                                   [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< rqt_publisher                                   [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< rqt_py_console                                  [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< rqt_robot_dashboard                             [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< rqt_robot_monitor                               [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< rqt_robot_plugins                               [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< rqt_robot_steering                              [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< rqt_runtime_monitor                             [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< rqt_service_caller                              [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< rqt_shell                                       [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< rqt_srv                                         [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< rqt_tf_tree                                     [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< rqt_top                                         [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< rqt_topic                                       [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< rqt_web                                         [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< simulators                                      [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< smach                                           [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< smclib                                          [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< stage                                           [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< std_msgs                                        [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< actionlib_msgs                                  [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< bond                                            [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< controller_manager_msgs                         [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< diagnostic_msgs                                 [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< geometry_msgs                                   [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< eigen_conversions                               [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< kdl_conversions                                 [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< nav_msgs                                        [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< rosgraph_msgs                                   [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< rqt_py_common                                   [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< shape_msgs                                      [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< smach_msgs                                      [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< std_srvs                                        [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< tf2_msgs                                        [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< tf2                                             [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< tf2_eigen                                       [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< trajectory_msgs                                 [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< control_msgs                                    [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< urdf_parser_plugin                              [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< urdf_sim_tutorial                               [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< urdfdom_py                                      [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< vision_opencv                                   [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< visualization_msgs                              [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< visualization_tutorials                         [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< viz                                             [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< webkit_dependency                               [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< xmlrpcpp                                        [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< roscpp                                          [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< bondcpp                                         [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< bondpy                                          [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< hardware_interface                              [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< controller_interface                            [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< nodelet                                         [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< nodelet_tutorial_math                           [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< pluginlib_tutorials                             [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< roscpp_tutorials                                [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< rosout                                          [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< camera_calibration                              [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< diagnostic_aggregator                           [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< diagnostic_updater                              [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< diagnostic_common_diagnostics                   [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< dynamic_reconfigure                             [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< filters                                         [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< joint_state_publisher                           [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< message_filters                                 [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< rosbag_storage                                  [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< rosmsg                                          [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< rosnode                                         [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< rospy_tutorials                                 [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< rostopic                                        [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< rqt_gui_cpp                                     [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< rqt_gui_py                                      [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< rqt_reconfigure                                 [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< self_test                                       [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< smach_ros                                       [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< tf2_py                                          [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< topic_tools                                     [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< rosbag                                          [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< actionlib                                       [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< actionlib_tutorials                             [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< controller_manager                              [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< diagnostic_analysis                             [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< nodelet_topic_tools                             [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< realtime_tools                                  [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< control_toolbox                                 [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< forward_command_controller                      [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< position_controllers                            [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< roswtf                                          [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< rqt_launch                                      [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< sensor_msgs                                     [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< camera_calibration_parsers                      [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< cv_bridge                                       [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< gazebo_msgs                                     [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< image_geometry                                  [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< image_transport                                 [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< camera_info_manager                             [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< compressed_depth_image_transport                [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< compressed_image_transport                      [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< image_proc                                      [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< image_publisher                                 [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< joint_state_controller                          [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< map_msgs                                        [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< pcl_msgs                                        [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< pcl_conversions                                 [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< polled_camera                                   [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< rqt_image_view                                  [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< stereo_msgs                                     [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< image_view                                      [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< stereo_image_proc                               [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< tf2_ros                                         [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< depth_image_proc                                [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< tf                                              [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< gazebo_ros                                      [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< interactive_markers                             [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< interactive_marker_tutorials                    [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< pcl_ros                                         [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< stage_ros                                       [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< tf2_geometry_msgs                               [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< image_rotate                                    [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< laser_geometry                                  [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< laser_assembler                                 [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< laser_filters                                   [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< tf2_kdl                                         [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< tf_conversions                                  [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< theora_image_transport                          [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< transmission_interface                          [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< turtlesim                                       [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< turtle_actionlib                                [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< turtle_tf                                       [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< turtle_tf2                                      [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< urdf                                            [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< gazebo_plugins                                  [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< joint_limits_interface                          [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< gazebo_ros_control                              [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< kdl_parser                                      [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< kdl_parser_py                                   [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< robot_state_publisher                           [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< rviz                                            [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< rviz_python_tutorial                            [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< urdf_tutorial                                   [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< visualization_marker_tutorials                  [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< xacro                                           [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< diff_drive_controller                           [ Unrelated job failed ]
[build] Summary: 0 of 234 packages succeeded.                                  
[build]   Ignored:   3 packages were skipped or are blacklisted.               
[build]   Warnings:  None.                                                     
[build]   Abandoned: 233 packages were abandoned.                              
[build]   Failed:    1 packages failed.                                        
[build] Runtime: 8.0 seconds total.
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests you need to have `python-empty` installed. Running `sudo apt-get install python3-empty`. All of that being said, you really shouldn't be trying to run ros melodic with python3. While it's technically possible like the article suggests it can cause a lot of other problems down the line. Melodic was built for python2 so that's what sort of package support you're going to find. If you need python3 you should be running Noetic on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: I see. Jetson doesnt have ubuntu 20 yet so i cant build noetic. And the application im trying to build nees python3 sipport. What do you suggest instead?

Comment: I guess it depends on what the application you're trying to use is. You can try to find a python2 version of whatever you're trying to use; however, I assume this doesn't exist since you're searching. Other than that the best solution would be to abstract out the ros bits from the python3 node(s) and have python3/python2 code talk in some other way than ros(TCP/UDP socket).